# Cron jobs with Expression Engine 2?

Tags: cron, expressionengine

I'm developing an Expression Engine site. The site has a database table populated from an external feed, and this feed needs to be parsed twice daily.

Obviously, a cron job seems a good fit for this, but where I'm struggling is, where do I put the code for this? I want to use the EE framework, and have the cron job hit a URL, but I don't really want to create a template just to drop some Expression Engine template tags into in order to run an action.

Is there an alternative way to create a script that I can use the Expression Engine core, but not have to create a template and template tag for it?

Answer (score 1):

EE doesn't have an internal faux-cron process you can hook into, but there is a [first-party add-on](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/expressionengine_cron/) that can do the trick. The thing is, it requires a plugin method or module class and module method be passed to it, not a URL. So, you'd have to write a quick plugin that, when executed, calls your action URL via cURL or what-have-you.

On the commercial side, there's the $35 [Automat:ee module](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/automatee) that *can* hit a URL in a simulated cron job.